# Django Table2 reverse ManyTomany

Tags: django

Here is my models :

```
class Appellation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class Ranking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=200)
    initials = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    appellation = models.ManyToManyField(Appellation)
```

In the Ranking Table, i arrived to have a column with all the appellation of a ranking :

```
appellation = tables.ManyToManyColumn(lambda obj: format_html('<span class="badge py-3 px-4 fs-7 badge-light-primary">{}</span>', str(obj)),
                                          separator=' ')
```

[image]

It's OK.

No, i would like to have in the Appellation Table, a column with all the rankings of the appellation.

Thanks you for your help.

Regards

Comment: I don't quite understand your intent, to get better feedbacks, I suggest you improve on the question structure

Answer (score 0):

In order to help :

models.py :

```
class Appellation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 @property 
    def rankings(self):
        appellation_instance = Appellation.objects.get(id=self.pk)
        rankings_for_this_appellation = appellation_instance.ranking_set.all()
        return rankings_for_this_appellation
```

Now in tables.py

```
class AppellationTable(tables.Table):

rankings = tables.ManyToManyColumn(lambda obj: format_html('<span class="badge py-3 px-4 fs-7 badge-light-primary">{}</span>', str(obj.initials)),
                                          separator=' ')    
    class Meta:
        model = Appellation
```

thanks godd0t :)

All is perfect, you can play with all the Ranking table fields :str(obj.initials)

Note : It consumes a lot of SQL calls because it does inner joins on each line. Any idea to reduce this?